# Filtering for multiple strings within the same column in r

Tags: r, string, filter, subset

My large data set (Groceries) has a column in it containing character data (Fruits) all of which is lower case and all of which contains no punctuation.

It looks a bit like this:

```
# Groceries Data Frame
Id    Groceries$Fruits
1     apple orange banana lemon grapefruit
2     grapes tomato passion fruit
3     strawberry orange kiwi
4     lemon orange passion fruit grapefruit lime
5     lemon orange passion fruit grapefruit lime peach
  ...
```

I'm trying to select all the rows (of which there are 3,320) from the Fruits column that contain 5 specific fruits (orange, lime, lemon, grapefruit & passion fruit). Initially I'm only interested in the rows that contain all 5 of these fruits and no additional Fruits. Thus, the only row out of these 5 that should be filtered/subsetted would be row 4. The fruits do not have to be in any particular order.

The data is actually answers to a test, so eventually I'm interested in determining who got 0/5 fruits, who got 1/5, 2/5 and so on...

I've tried 2 methods so far, both to no avail. 
Firstly I tried using grep(), but no rows were stored in the resulting data frame.

```
# 1st attempt with grep()
Correct fruits <- Groceries[grep("orange, lemon, lime, passion fruit, 
grapefruit", Groceries$Fruits), ]
```

And then I tried using filter(), but the selected rows don't contain just the 5 Fruits I'm seeking out, it selects all rows that contain any of the 5 fruits.

```
# 2nd attempt with filter
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
CorrectFruits <- c("lemon", "orange", "passion fruit", "grapefruit", 
"lime")

filter <- Groceries %>%
  select(Id, Fruits) %>%
  filter(str_detect(tolower(Fruits), pattern = CorrectFruits))
```

The result I'm after initially is a new DF containing all the columns in the Groceries table, but only the rows of those people who got all 5 of the chosen fruits correct.

Next, it would be cool to select the opposite; everyone who didn't get all 5 correct.

Finally, I'd love to be able to subset those who got a specific proportion correct. I.e. row 1 got 3 correct, row 2 only got 1 correct and row 3 only got 1 correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's an example of what some of the columns look like:

```
# Groceries
Id   Age      Nationality    Colour question   Fruits question
1    26-35    Canadian       Red               apple orange banana lemon grapefruit
2    26-35    US             Blue              grapes tomato passion fruit
3    46-55    Canadian       Red               strawberry orange kiwi
4    55+      US             Red               lemon orange passion fruit grapefruit lime
5    36-45    British        Green             lemon orange passion fruit grapefruit lime peach
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example of the Grocery dataset? Partial data would help.

Comment: Hi Jim O, thanks for getting back so quick, I've added a short example of what some of the data looks like at the bottom, although the dataset is thousands of rows long. Let me know some specifics if I can can usefully add anything else

Comment: Sure, I will try. But to assist you better, is your query always limited to 5 fruits?

Comment: Yes the question was 'name as many of these 5 fruits as you can' and it had 5 separate pictures of the 5 fruits listed above

Comment: I would suggest not naming your function `filter` if you're working in the `tidyverse` to avoid potenital conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Might need more clarification on what you intend on doing with answers that have all 5 fruits with some extra, but this should help you out. I substituted all instances of "passion fruit" with "passionfruit" to make it easier:

```
df$Fruits <- gsub("passion fruit", "passionfruit", df$Fruits)
CorrectFruits <- c("lemon", "orange", "passionfruit", "grapefruit", 
                   "lime")
df$Count <- str_count(df$Fruits, paste(CorrectFruits, collapse = '|'))
df$Count <- ifelse((df$Count == 5 & str_count(df$Fruits, '\\w+') > 5), 0, df$Count)
```

which gives

```
ID                                          Fruits Count
1            apple orange banana lemon grapefruit     3
2                      grapes tomato passionfruit     1
3                          strawberry orange kiwi     1
4       lemon orange passionfruit grapefruit lime     5
5 lemon orange passionfruit grapefruit lime peach     0
```

First line does the passionfruit substitution, and then str_count counts all occurrences of correct fruits in `df$Fruit`. Finally, if all 5 fruits are correct but there are extras, `Count` resets to 0.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks a ton. I have 2 follow ups if you'd be willing... 1) in terms of the additional fruit answers, how could you change the code so that instead of resetting their score to 0, they lost a point for every additional fruit? 2) If I wanted to create a new df, keeping all of the data from the Groceries data frame, but only the rows of those with a score of 5, how could I do that?

Comment: I didn't understand the first follow up question. Please look at my Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer after seeing others' genius solutions.

```
ID <- c(1:5)
Age <- c("26-35", "26-35", "46-55", "55+", "56-45")
Nationality <- c("Canadian", "US", "Canadian", "US", "British")
Color <- c("Correct", "Incorrect", "Incorrect", "Correct", "Correect")
Fruits <- c("pineapple", 
            "apple", 
            "apple orange kiwi fifth",
            "orange apple pineapple kiwi fifth",
            "pineapple orange apple fifth kiwi"
            )
df <- data.frame(ID, Age, Nationality, Color, Fruits)
df
```

**heds1**'s reponse looks great. However, you want to be careful using string exacts such as `grepl` because it could return compound words. For example, consider the word *pineapple*; it contains *pine* and *apple*. Notice here that searching for apple returns pineapples.

```
filter(df, grepl("apple", Fruits))

  ID   Age Nationality     Color                            Fruits
1  1 26-35    Canadian   Correct                         pineapple
2  2 26-35          US Incorrect                             apple
3  3 46-55    Canadian Incorrect           apple orange kiwi fifth
4  4   55+          US   Correct orange apple pineapple kiwi fifth
5  5 56-45     British  Correect pineapple orange apple fifth kiwi
```

The answer provided by **sumshyftw** is awesome. And I love that I am learning something from **sumshyftw**. But to demonstrate my point that unrestrained string search could mess your count:

```
CorrectFruits <- c("apple")
df$Count <- str_count(df$Fruits, paste(CorrectFruits, collapse = '|'))
df$Count <- ifelse((df$Count == 5 & str_count(df$Fruits, '\\w+') > 5), 0, df$Count)
df

  ID   Age Nationality     Color                            Fruits Count
1  1 26-35    Canadian   Correct                         pineapple     1
2  2 26-35          US Incorrect                             apple     1
3  3 46-55    Canadian Incorrect           apple orange kiwi fifth     1
4  4   55+          US   Correct orange apple pineapple kiwi fifth     2
5  5 56-45     British  Correect pineapple orange apple fifth kiwi     2
```

Notice that it counted the pineapple as a correct answer despite that the only correct fruit is an apple. To overcome this, you want to wrap your words with `\\b`.

```
CorrectFruits <- c("\\bapple\\b")
df$Count <- str_count(df$Fruits, paste(CorrectFruits, collapse = '|'))
df$Count <- ifelse((df$Count == 5 & str_count(df$Fruits, '\\w+') > 5), 0, df$Count)
df

  ID   Age Nationality     Color                            Fruits Count
1  1 26-35    Canadian   Correct                         pineapple     0
2  2 26-35          US Incorrect                             apple     1
3  3 46-55    Canadian Incorrect           apple orange kiwi fifth     1
4  4   55+          US   Correct orange apple pineapple kiwi fifth     1
5  5 56-45     British  Correect pineapple orange apple fifth kiwi     1
```

R no longer counts pineapple as an apple.

But for the record, **sumshyftw** deserves the credit for working out the hard part in my example:

```
CorrectFruits <- c("\\bapple\\b", "\\borange\\b", "\\bpineapple\\b", "\\bfifth\\b", "\\bkiwi\\b")
df$Count <- str_count(df$Fruits, paste(CorrectFruits, collapse = '|'))
df$Count <- ifelse((df$Count == 5 & str_count(df$Fruits, '\\w+') > 5), 0, df$Count)
df

  ID   Age Nationality     Color                            Fruits Count
1  1 26-35    Canadian   Correct                         pineapple     1
2  2 26-35          US Incorrect                             apple     1
3  3 46-55    Canadian Incorrect           apple orange kiwi fifth     4
4  4   55+          US   Correct orange apple pineapple kiwi fifth     5
5  5 56-45     British  Correect pineapple orange apple fifth kiwi     5
```

To show only those with all five fruits:

```
df2 <- filter(df, df$Count == 5)
df2

  ID   Age Nationality    Color                            Fruits Count
1  4   55+          US  Correct orange apple pineapple kiwi fifth     5
2  5 56-45     British Correect pineapple orange apple fifth kiwi     5
```

Comment: Didn't even consider the issues with pineapple! Love your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `grepl` with a target list of keywords.

```
df <- structure(list(v1 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("row1", "row2", 
"row3", "row4"), class = "factor"), v2 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("another invalid row", "apple banana mandarin orange pear", 
"banana apple mandarin pear orange", "not a valid row"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

targets <- c("banana", "apple", "orange", "pear", "mandarin")
bool_df <- as.data.frame(sapply(targets, grepl, df$v2))
match_rows <- which(rowSums(bool_df) == 5)
df <- df[match_rows,]
```

You can then change the criteria in the `match_rows` vector by changing the `5` to, for example `4` for four fruit matches, etc.